# Extract only certain files from a folder in python as list

Tags: python, list, extract, filenames, glob

I have the following list of files in my folder:

```
data.txt
an_123.txt
info.log
an_234.txt
filename.txt
main.py
an_55.txt
```

I would like to extract only the `.txt` files that have prefix `an` as list. The output should look like the following:

```
[an_123.txt,
an_234.txt,
an_55.txt]
```

What I tried so far?

```
import glob
mylist = [f for f in glob.glob("*.txt")]
```

This prints all the '.txt' files. How do I extract only the filenames that have 'an'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to describe what you want in language `glob.glob` understands, your code after minimal change might look as follows:

```
import glob
mylist = [f for f in glob.glob("an*.txt")]
```

considering that `glob.glob` itself returns list this might be simplified to

```
import glob
mylist = glob.glob("an*.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use list comprehension:

```
import os

files_list = [f for f in os.listdir() if f[:2] == 'an']
```